# I am not able to give a link to the icon in the list

Tags: html, css

So this is code of a bootstrap template

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#main-header"><i class="icon-home"</i></a></li>
<li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The internal link is working but I am not able to link it to external html doc via the icon. This is the code I gave...........(change in the first list item)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you give an explanation a bit more detailed ? so that anyone who doesn't know anything about your problem can help you...

Comment: Where is index.html? is it in the same folder? If yes, then use <a href="./index.html">

Comment: Give full path of the file in `href` of `<a>`.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @NoopurDabhi - it still isn't working.....yes,it is in the same folder

Comment: @HarishKommuri - it still isn't working

Comment: @AjeetShah - no error message, it doesn't perform any function when clicked

Comment: @SrishtiKaushal Could you please show us your directory structure and indicating the potential files in use?

Comment: @AjeetShah - its in a folder on desktop. the main file is named index and the second html file is named image. This is the code written in image to go back to index. both html files are in same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, I just replaced the icon class.

Run in full screen mode(as you are using an `md` offset) :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" ></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#info">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the code...it is working when i run on this page, but still not working when i add in the code.....any other changes I should make?

Comment: Check console for errors. Also post what is the output you are getting?

Comment: its no o/p....there is no action being performed....i changed the class for home btn as nav navbar-default, and the link is working. but its only coming when I am creating a separate ul for it.....

Comment: Put up a fiddle maybe I can help you.